# Library enforcing one person at a time for reading (block concurrent read)

Tags: item-level-permissions, read-only, concurrency

In order to be compliant with a digital document licensing model - no concurrent access, which requires that a given (read-only) digital document is blocked even for reading while it is open by someone else, I wonder how to best enforce this in a SharePoint Library.

The idea is, a library contains PDF documents. When a user opens a document to read it, it should be the equivalent of a check-out but also preventing anyone else to open it until it is released by its user.

Of course the user name must show up in a column so another user can request the blocking user to release it. I'm thinking of workflows modifying the access rights on the fly at the item level but wonder if it's the best option.

(This is for a corporate library of DIN/ISO normative documents, for which the Swiss Editor provides a very interesting licensing model, "paper-like", one reader at a time, which is much less expensive than a site-wide license.)

Comment: SharePoint doesn't trigger any kind of event when a user opens a document for reading, I am not aware of any way you could implement this, every with adding custom code.

Comment: I know, but I was thinking of something along the lines of 1) a workflow to populate a list containing all the documents name/title available in the library where nobody has access by default, 2) a manual workflow "Request document access" that users can manually launch against this list, which checks if the document is free and gives read access to it (while updating the list with the name of requestor), or denies otherwise.

Comment: Is there a reason these files need to "live" in SharePoint?  With this level of customization, and given that you purposefully do not want any users to accessb the files directly, let alone perform any kind of collaboration on them, I would think keeping them in some type of secured storage like bon on-prem fileshare, or in Azure Storage would be a better repo.  I suppose you could keep your "who has the file locked for reading" metadata in a SharePoint list, especially if you are trying to stick with a low-code solution like Power Automate for your "checkout" process.

Comment: Rather than changing item-level permissions, build a UI in PowerApps or in the preview-mode Flow UI, to present or display the file (s) to the user that they have reserved from your system.  As long as the app's connection has permissions to get the file, no other users would ever need direct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solved the issue by buying an Enterprise license from ISO allowing me to share these documents and used a standard Sharepoint library.